# pdo sqlite::memory: sharing and lifetime

Tags: sqlite, pdo, in-memory-database

Can anybody explain me how sqlite::memory works? As I understood it works only per instance, so you can't for example create db schema using one instance of PDO and fill the just created table via another PDO instance with sqlite::memory ?
You only have to pass the PDO instance as param or make it global?

Why am I asking, it's because I'm reading a book about unit testing and in one of examples they create a memory db with table Users and fill it with one record, and that is done in phpUnit setUp() method and the reading of table is done by another instance of PDO  which is created in real code which have to be tested. 
It seems logical for me that each instance of PDO memory db has it's own separate db, but maybe I'm missing something.
Would appreciate your opinions, thanks.

```
$schema =<<<SQL
CREATE TABLE "Users" (
"id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
"username" VARCHAR UNIQUE NOT NULL,
"email" VARCHAR UNIQUE NOT NULL,
"code" VARCHAR
);
SQL;

$dsn = 'sqlite::memory:';

//instance1
$db1 = new PDO($dsn);
$db1->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db1->exec($schema);

$db1->exec(
     "INSERT INTO Users(username, email)
     VALUES('John Doe', 'user@example . com');"
 );

$statement1 = $db1->prepare('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email =:email;');
var_dump($statement1); echo PHP_EOL; //object(PDOStatement)....

//instance2 tring to access inst1 memory db and fails
$db2 = new PDO($dsn); //also memory db
$db2->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$statement2 = $db2->prepare('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email =:email;');
var_dump($statement2); echo PHP_EOL; //PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: Users ....
```

Answer (score 2):

As shown by your code, each `new PDO('sqlite::memory:')` call creates a new, independent in-memory database.

I don't know what that book does, but if you want to re-use an in-memory database, you have to ensure that the test setup and your actual code share the same database connection.